# Mongo Auth fail when using mongod.conf

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to learn about mongo and how to secure it. I manage to make it work using command line but when I try to use a conf file I get erros on authentication.

I have created an admin user like:

```
use admin
var admin = {
    user:"admin",
    pwd:"123456",
    roles:[
        {
            role: "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            db:"admin"
        }
    ]
}
db.createUser(admin)
```

Starting mongod `mongod --auth` and connecting to it using `mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 --authenticationDatabase admin -u admin -p` works.

I would like to move from command line to a conf file.
For that purpose, I create the following `mongod.conf` file:

mongod.conf

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /Users/me/Web/blog/setup/logs/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

I run the daemon by invoking `mongod -f mongod.conf`.
I try to authenticate in mongo by invoking the previous command that used to work but this time it does not work:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 --authenticationDatabase admin -u admin -p

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5
Enter password: 
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2018-05-11T08:50:53.908+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1441:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

exception: login failed
```

Am I typing something wrong? I dont see what is the issue in here. Something missing in the conf file or wrong params invoking `mongo`?

Comment: Check your mongodb.log, you can see what config file parameters mongod used when started. When you wrote your config file, you used space chars for ident, not tab?

Comment: @kitimenpolku, It seemes like that you are writing wrong authentication command in mongo shell , such as from your log "mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 --authenticationDatabase admin -u admin -p"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your log statement it seems like that you are committing mistake in your authentication statement such as in your statement

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 --authenticationDatabase admin -u admin -p
```

As per MongoDB BOL documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) With access control enabled, ensure you have a user with [userAdmin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdmin) or [userAdminAnyDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdminAnyDatabase) role in the admin database. This user can administrate user and roles such as: create users, grant or revoke roles from users, and create or modify customs roles.

**Connect and authenticate as the user administrator**

Using the [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell, you can:

- Connect with authentication by passing in user credentials, or
- Connect first withouth authentication, and then issue the  [db.auth()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.auth/#db.auth)
  method to authenticate.

For example, the following creates the user `myUserAdmin` in the `admin` database:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

***To authenticate during connection***

Start a [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell with the -u , -p , and the --authenticationDatabase  command line options:

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

***To authenticate after connecting***

Connect the [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell to the  [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod):

```
mongo --port 27017
```

Switch to the authentication database (in this case, admin), and use `db.auth(<username>, <pwd>)` method to authenticate:

```
use admin
db.auth("myUserAdmin", "abc123" )
```

As I am able to see that in your below mention `mongod.conf` file the `authorization : enable` . It's means your authentication is enable. So, there is no issue in your `mongod.conf` file.

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /Users/me/Web/blog/setup/logs/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

For your further ref [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/FMqVcnkrxtU) and [here](https://medium.com/@matteocontrini/how-to-setup-auth-in-mongodb-3-0-properly-86b60aeef7e8)